# Sql query to determine unallocated time

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table having column BOOKING, START_TIME, END_TIME. Lets say couple of the rows of a BOOKING 'A' contains data as follows:

```
       BOOKING, START_TIME, END_TIME

         A    | 2PM      | 3PM
         A    | 6PM      | 7PM
```

I want to know the time between 2-7 PM when booking for A is not done?

For example, in the above case 4-6 PM is the time when booking is not done.

Comment: So what is the question?  Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Comment: Are these times stored as `time` data type or `timestamp`. Or just plain strings.

Comment: @ambianBeing time data type

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza plz read the post completely and then ask what is my question coz as I can see my question is quite visible in my post

Comment: Each Line represents a booking with a given Start and end. He wants to know the time intervals where there is No booking yet. Seems like bookings can only be created between 2 and 7. So with the available bookings the remaining free time is between 3 and 6.

Comment: what is your mysql version.

Comment: Why the result is 4-6 pm and not 3-6 pm ?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza my apology, yes the result should be 3-6pm

Comment: so 2pm to 3pm actually mean 2:00 to 2:59?

Answer (score 1):

[**SQL DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ef766b/8)

```
SELECT t1.`BOOKING`
     , t1.`START_TIME`, t1.`END_TIME`
     , t2.`START_TIME`, t2.`END_TIME`
     , DATE_ADD(t1.`END_TIME`, INTERVAL 1 HOUR)  as  unallocated_start
     , t2.`START_TIME`as  unallocated_end
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table1 t2
  ON t1.`END_TIME` < t2.`START_TIME`
 AND t1.`BOOKING` = t2.`BOOKING`
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM Table1 t3
                  WHERE t3.`BOOKING` = t1.`BOOKING`
                    AND t3.`START_TIME` > t1.`END_TIME` 
                    AND t3.`START_TIME` < t2.`START_TIME`);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| BOOKING | START_TIME | END_TIME | START_TIME | END_TIME | unallocated_start | unallocated_end |
|---------|------------|----------|------------|----------|-------------------|-----------------|
|       A |   14:00:00 | 15:00:00 |   18:00:00 | 19:00:00 |          16:00:00 |        18:00:00 |
|       A |   18:00:00 | 19:00:00 |   20:00:00 | 23:00:00 |          20:00:00 |        20:00:00 |
|       B |   04:00:00 | 10:00:00 |   13:00:00 | 19:00:00 |          11:00:00 |        13:00:00 |
```

Comment: Did you try it? Only need to remove the `INTERVAL 1 HOUR`